# shaders not causing any effect - opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

I'm trying to render on a Texture which resides in another class and I can't look at the code. I just have the access to it's pointer which is created by `glGenTextures`.

I'm trying to render on this texture. I'm creating my own shaders and linking to it but they don't affect anything. I just see a white screen on my phone. I've put opengl error check after every statement, and it passes without any error.

I wanted to ask, could there be any previously attached shaders to that texture or something like that which are hindering my own shaders. (I don't even know if this statement makes any sense.)

I'm using the utility class from grafika for program and shaders creation - https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/GlUtil.java . That's why I'm pretty much sure my shaders related code is okay.

This is my main drawing loop -

```
log("Receiving frame");
                GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mainTexture.glName);
//                  
                // Copy the model / view / projection matrix over.
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixLoc, 1, false, GlUtil.IDENTITY_MATRIX, 0);
                GlUtil.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

                // Copy the texture transformation matrix over.
                /*
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muTexMatrixLoc, 1, false, texMatrix, 0);
                GlUtil.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv"); */

                // Enable the "aPosition" vertex attribute.
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionLoc);
                GlUtil.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

                // Connect vertexBuffer to "aPosition".
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionLoc, 2,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * GlUtil.SIZEOF_FLOAT, GlUtil.FULL_RECTANGLE_BUF);
                GlUtil.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

                // Enable the "aTextureCoord" vertex attribute.
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureCoordLoc);
                GlUtil.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

                // Connect texBuffer to "aTextureCoord".

                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureCoordLoc, 2,
                        GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * GlUtil.SIZEOF_FLOAT, GlUtil.FULL_RECTANGLE_TEX_BUF);
                    GlUtil.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
                GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, parameters.getPreviewSize().width, parameters.getPreviewSize().height);
                GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

This is my fragment shader code -

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER_2D =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor[0] = 1.0;gl_FragColor[1] = 0.0;gl_FragColor[2] = 0.0;gl_FragColor[3] = 1.0;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

These are the coordinate matrices -

```
private static final float FULL_RECTANGLE_COORDS[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,   // 0 bottom left
     1.0f, -1.0f,   // 1 bottom right
    -1.0f,  1.0f,   // 2 top left
     1.0f,  1.0f,   // 3 top right
};

private static final float FULL_RECTANGLE_TEX_COORDS[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,     // 0 bottom left
    45.0f, 0.0f,     // 1 bottom right
    0.0f, 1.0f,     // 2 top left
    56.0f, 344.0f      // 3 top right
};
```

Comment: Your texture coordinates look very odd. They are typically in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any code for connecting your texture to "sTexture". You are using texture slot 2 for your texture, so you need tell the shader this:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);  // using texture slot 2
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mainTexture.glName);

int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (programHandle, "sTexture" );
GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc2, 2); // connect sTexture to texture slot 2
```